# Google DataStore PHP GDS fetchPage from record

Tags: php, google-cloud-datastore

PHP-GDS provides the following method:

```
$obj_store->fetchPage(10);  // Gets the first 10 books
```

However this only works within the same connection, I'd like to use something like:

```
$obj_store->fetchPage(n, 10);
```

so I can get a set of items from  separate API calls, e.g.:

```
api.php?page=1&items=10 // items 0-10
api.php?page=2&items=10 // items 11-20
api.php?page=3&items=10 // items 21-30
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm the author of php-gds (https://github.com/tomwalder/php-gds)

You can do exactly what you are asking, the second parameter to fetchPage() is the OFFSET.

`fetchPage(10); // gets first 10`

`fetchPage(10, 10); // gets 11-20`

`fetchPage(10, 20); // gets 21-30`

This can be expensive, as `fetchPage(10, 5000)` will scan 5,010 rows. You may be better off using cursors if your offsets are going to be large.

For more details, see here:

https://github.com/tomwalder/php-gds#limits-offsets--cursors

Comment: Thanks Tom I ended up creating an implementation that uses cursors.

Comment: Great stuff, glad I could help out.